# build authenticatoin sever for web. Use OTP

Tags: freeradius, google-authenticator

I have a web app. I want to use OTP for it so i build a authentication server.

This server use freeradius and google authenticator. I want to ask how to integrate freeradius and google authenticator for user of web.

Tks your attention.

Comment: So I understand you correctly that you have a web application and you want to protect this web application with OTP?
You can use the google authenticator as the 2nd factor of the users generting the one time password. But your web application needs some logic to verify the one time password. 
Why did you come up wtih freeradius in the first place? You probably do not want to teach your web application to talk RADIUS.

Comment: sorry for my late reply.

i want to build a authentication server with freeradius and gg authenticator. Then i will integrate them with my web. but i don't know how to my web to talk with my authentication server. 

Tks for your reply

Comment: If your authentication server uses the RADIUS protocol for authentication, you web application should obviously be the RADIUS client and also talk RADIUS. The book "FreeRADIUS  Beginner's Guide" is a great read!